# Adding Shadows to Hair Particle Emitter

Tags: hair, shadows

I've been using *Grass Essentials* for grass in my scene, but I've recently noticed that the grass isn't casting shadows. I've added a bright light to amplify the issue below. The first image is from the rendered viewport, the second is the scene render.

[image]

[image]

Previous answers online don't seem to be of any help here.

- Converting ~60,000 grass strands to a mesh is not an option.
- *Strand Render* is no longer an option in 2.81, and isn't relevant here since this uses a *Collection* as the render object.
- All *Ray Visibility* options are enabled for the emitting ground plane.

The Render settings for the particle emitter are shown below. Thanks for any help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed - even though the "hair shape" doesn't directly affect the appearance of the individual strands of grass, it apparently was affecting the shadow. I just boosted the *tip* thickness, and *radius scale* of the particle emitter.

[image]